# Initializing const pointer - initializer list in c++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to implement tree structure in C++. I started with following code:

```
class Tree {
    Node * const first;
    Node * last;
public:

    Tree(Node * const root)             
        {
            first = root;
            last = first;
        };
}
```

But of course it gave me these errors:

> error: uninitialized member ‘Tree::first’ with ‘const’ type ‘Node*
>   const’ [-fpermissive]
>
> error: assignment of read-only member
>   ‘Tree::first’

I looked into the problem and found out that I have to use `initializer list`. I tried, but it didn't go very well.

```
Tree(Node * const root)
:first()              
{
    first->id = 0;
    first->sibling = first;
    first->point = root->point;
    last = first;
};
```

With this, the problem ends with "Run failed", no errors, no exceptions.

So I even tried just:

```
Tree(Node * const root)
:first()              
{
};
```

But the Node constructor isn't even called..

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not *initializing* your `const` pointer, but *assigning* to it. As it is `const`, you cannot do that. You must initialize it in the constructor initialization list:

```
Tree(Node * const root) : first(root)
{
  ....
}
```

Remember, once you get to the constructor's body, all data members have been initialized, be it implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Okay this is the correct answer. However I am even more lost now, could you, please, explain (or just point me to a source) what actually happens in "first(root)"?

Comment: @KubaSpatny what happens is that `first` is initialized to hold the value of `root`, i.e. it points to whatever `root` points to.